# Recursive Function to generate / print a Fibonacci series

Tags: matlab, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function call method that would print the Fibonacci until a specific location:

```
1 function f = fibonacci(n)
2 fprintf('The value is %d\n', n)
3 if (n==1)
4     f(1) = 1;
5     return;
6 elseif (n == 2)
7     f(2) = 2;
8 else
9     f(n) = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);   
10 end
11 end
```

As per my understanding the fibonacci function would be called recursively until value of argument n passed to it is 1. Then the function stack would rollback accordingly. So when I call this function from command:

```
>> fibonacci(4)
```

The value of n is 4, so line 9 would execute like:

```
9 f(4) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2);
```

Now I believe that that first fibonacci(3) would be called - hence again for fibonacci(3)

```
9 if(3) = fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1);
```

The ifs in line number 3 and 6 would take care.

But now how  fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1) statement would change to:

```
 if(3) = 2 + 1;
```

I am receiving the below error and unable to debug further to resolve it:

```
>> fibonacci(4)
The value is 4
The value is 3
The value is 2
The value is 1
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in fibonacci (line 9)
    f(n) = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);

Error in fibonacci (line 9)
    f(n) = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
```

Please provide some insight for the solution and with which parameter would fibonacci function be recursively called at line number 9 first and consequently.

Ex For n = 4

```
f(n) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2);
```

So will MATLAB call fibonacci(3) or fibonacci(2) first?

Shouldn't the code be some thing like below:

```
1 function f = fibonacci(n)
2 fprintf('The valus is %d\n', n)
3 if (n==1)
4     f(1) = 1;
5     return f(1);
6 elseif (n == 2)
7     f(2) = 2;
8    return f(2);
9 else
10   f(n) = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);   
11 end
12 end
```

> > fibonacci(4)
> >     Error: File: fibonacci.m Line: 5 Column: 12
> >     Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Why return expression in a function is resulting in an error?

Comment: I am not an expert in MATLAB, but looking here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html it says that return is done, in your case, like `f = 1` and not `f(1)=1`? I might be wrong.

Comment: Then what value will the recursed function return in our case ' f(4) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2);' would result to what after the return statement execution

Comment: I think  you need to edit "return f(1);" and "return f(2);" to "return;".

Comment: Still the same error if I replace as per @Divakar

Comment: I think that you need to change `f(1)=1;` to `f=1;` and `f(2)=2` to `f=2`, and also `return f(1)` and `return f(2)` to `return`. Finally `f(n) = ...` to `f=...`;

Comment: Yes I get the correct answer after changes as suggested by @D.Kasipovic but what if I need to print the whole fibonacci-series to that location as passed as a parameter to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function f = fibonacci(n)
 if (n==1)
     f= 1;
 elseif (n == 2)
     f = 2;
 else
     f = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);   
 end
```

Note that this is also a recursion (that only evaluates each n once):

```
function f=fibonacci(n)
  f=additive(n,1,2);

function a=additive(n,x0,x1)
  if(n==1)
    a=x0;
  else 
    if(n==2)
      a=x1;
    else 
      a=additive(n-1,x1,x0+x1);
    end
  end
```

Comment: However, I have to say that this not the most efficient way to do this! There other much more efficient ways, such as using the golden ratio, for instance. Or maybe another more efficient recursion where the same branches are not called more than once!

Comment: Thanks - I agree. The above code prints the fibonacci series value at that location as passed as a parameter - is it possible to print the full fibonacci series via recursive method?

Comment: It does not seem to be natural to do this, since the same n is called more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If you HAVE to use recursive approach, try this -

```
function out = fibonacci(n)
fprintf('The valus is %d\n', n)

if (n==1)
    out = 1;
    return;
elseif (n == 2)
    out = 2;
    return;
else
    out = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
end

return;
```

Unlike C/C++, in MATLAB with 'return', one can't return a value, but only the control goes back to the calling function. The output to be returned to the calling function is to be stored in the output variable that is defined at the start of the function.

**EDIT 1:** For the entire fibonacci series and which assumes that the series starts from 1, use this -

```
N = 16; %// Number of fibonacci numbers needed

all_nums = zeros(1,N);
all_nums(1) = 1;
for k = 2:N
    all_nums(k) = fibonacci(k-1);
end
```

Gives -

```
1     1     2     3     5     8    13    21    34    55    89   144   233   377   610   987
```

Comment: But that prints the fibonacci series value at that location - is it possible to print the full fibonacci series?

Answer (score 0):

Create a M-file for fibonacci function and write code as given below

```
function [ result ] = fibonacci( n )

if n==0|n==1
    result = n;

else
    result = fibonacci(n-2)+fibonacci(n-1);
end
end
```

Write following code in command window of matlab

```
for n = 0:10
    fprintf('Fibonacci(%d)= %d\n', n, fibonacci(n));
    end
```

Output :-

```
Fibonacci(0)= 0
Fibonacci(1)= 1
Fibonacci(2)= 1
Fibonacci(3)= 2
Fibonacci(4)= 3
Fibonacci(5)= 5
Fibonacci(6)= 8
Fibonacci(7)= 13
Fibonacci(8)= 21
Fibonacci(9)= 34
Fibonacci(10)= 55
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function, which returns Integer:

```
func fibonacci(number n : Int) -> Int 
{
    guard n > 1 else {return n}
    return fibonacci(number: n-1) + fibonacci(number: n-2)
}
```

This will return the fibonacci output of n numbers, To print the series You can use this function like this in swift:

```
for _ in 0...10
{
    print(fibonacci(number : 10))
}
```

It will print the series of 10 numbers.